# Turning off Visual Flows through CCI

Tags: data, cumulusci

I would like to load large datasets using Snowfakery and CCI into a testing environment. There are some flows in the org that fail and prevent the data from getting loaded. What I am trying to figure out how to do is write a cci flow that will deactivate a list of visual flows, load the data, and then reactivate the flows. However, it looks like there's only a CCI task for activating the flows. What is the best way to achieve the deactivate step? Use UpdataData to modify the flow records?

Answer (score 1):

*I am a member of the Cumulus Suite team*.

CumulusCI currently supports activating and deactivating TDTM (Table Driven Trigger Management) triggers for NPSP and EDA, but does not offer the capability to turn on and off Flows or regular Apex triggers.

We would welcome a feature proposal as a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/SFDO-Tooling/CumulusCI/issues) but cannot make promises about prioritization.